# How to add two specific columns from a colSums table in r?

Tags: r, column-sum

I made a frequency table with two variables in a data frame using this:

```
    table(df$Variable1, df$Variable2)
```

The output was this:

```
             1    2    3    4    5    D    R
        1 5000   21   39    2   10    0  112
        2 1028   11   18    4    8    1   54
        3 1501    6   12    2    3    0   68
        4  355    2    4    0    0    0   23
        5  421    4    4    0    0    0   49
```

Then I wanted to find the sum of the first two columns so I did this:

```
    colSums(table(df$Variable1, df$Variable2))
```

The output was this:

```
       1    2    3    4    5    D    R 
     8305   44   77   8   21    1  306
```

Is there a way to find the sum of columns 1 and 2 from the colSums output above? What would the code be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use “[1:2,]” applied to result.

Comment: It’s not an R numeric vector. More like a matrix.

Comment: After applying `[1:2,]`, you should wrap everything inside `sum()`.  Unless I'm misreading your question

Comment: @MichaelDewar do you mean like this? "sum(colSums(table(df$Variable1, df$Variable2)) [1:2,])"

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what you are looking for.  Does it give the answer you want?